# Polynomial Reduction for restriction

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, np-complete

I ran across a polynomial reduction that used the fact that one language was a restriction of the other. Is that statement really true?
$$
L_1 \subseteq L_2 \rightarrow L_2 \leq_{p} L_1
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim in the question is false.

Every language contains the empty language as a subset ($\emptyset \subseteq L_2$) but the only languages that are polynomial time Turing reducible to the empty set ($L_2 \leq_p \emptyset$) are the ones that are decidable in polynomial time.

Similarly, every language is a subset of the language that includes every word ($L_2 \subseteq \Sigma^*$) but the only languages that are polynomial-time Turing reducible to $\Sigma^*$ (so $L_2 \leq_p \Sigma^*$) are the ones that are decidable in polynomial time.

There are similar issues if we are talking about polynomial-time many-one reducibility - the empty language and $\Sigma^*$ are also exceptional cases.

The claim in the original source could still be correct, if it uses other information that was in context there and which wasn't included here.

Comment: Thank you! It should be a reflex to verify with the empty set and the the language that includes everything right away

Comment: @DanielDanny Hi! I have trouble understanding how any language could be reduced to the empty language. Since the empty language does not contain any problem instances, how would a TM convert a problem instance from some language L to one in the empty language? Thank you!